C# Avalonia Scroll в ListBox
Несколько раз обновлял версии, сейчас Avalonia 11.0.11 и Net 8. Хочу, чтобы у LixtBox была вертикальная прокрутка. Добавил строчку
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
Всё компилируется, запускается, но полосы прокрутки нет, что не так делаю? View:
<UserControl
    xmlns:vm="using:Company.Template.Software.ViewModels"
    x:Class="Company.Template.Software.Views.StartView"
    x:DataType="vm:StartViewModel"
    xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignWidth="920"
    MinWidth="920"
    d:DesignHeight="600"
    MinHeight="600"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Viewbox>
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        Spacing="20">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="ID: " FontSize="16" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" FontSize="16" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="FullName: " FontSize="16" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="16" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Role: " FontSize="16" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Role}" FontSize="16" />
                        </StackPanel>                
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>  


Так у вас ViewBox стоит, что означает "Ей, подстрой размер элементов внутри под размер окна", вон они у вас вместо того, чтоб заходить за границы и показывать полосу прокрутки, делаются больше/меньше.

@EvgeniyZ без ViewBox тоже самое. И если я правильно понял, то даже с ViewBox полоса должна появиться, если режим Visible, а не Auto.

Тогда еще и StackPanel замените на Grid. Вам нужна панель, которая не растягивается за пределы дочернего элемента, а подстраивается под размеры родителя. "И если я правильно понял" - если она за пределами видимой области, нет, не появиться.

@EvgeniyZ убрал ViewBox, убрал вообще все StackPanel даже внутри ListBox. Обернул в Grid. Пока результат тот же.

Вот поведение в WPF проекте: ViewBox + StackPanel - как видите, контент просто меняет свои размеры, пытаясь подстроиться под дочернюю панель (окно). Просто StackPanel - тут уже размеры не меняет, но полосы прокрутки нет, ибо высота не имеет четких границ, она равна требуемой для контента высоты, из-за чего полоса не появляется (установите высоту, будет полоса). Меняем на Grid - и вот полосы появились, ибо Grid задает свои размеры равными размерами окна.

@EvgeniyZ да, получилось когда ещё учёл высоту окна, спасибо!
